# Split lastname out onto new line

Tags: regex, perl, unix, awk

I have file with and one line with in the file look like this

```
GIVEN=David Smith
GIVEN=John Doe Young
GIVEN=Ms Sam Parker
GIVEN=Mr James Free Foo ABC
GIVEN=Joe Cam-Barr
```

I just want to find anylines that start with `GIVEN` and find the last space character (assuming that is the last name) then make a new line.

So input =

```
FOO=Bar
GIVEN=David Smith
Baz=123
```

The output should be

```
FOO=Bar
GIVEN=David
LAST=Smith
Baz=123
```

This is as far as I could get:

```
(?<=(GIVEN=))(.*\ )
```

See here for demo http://regexr.com?30uh8

Comment: You want to do this in Perl? Awk?

Comment: +1 for sample input, expected output and some code. Good luck.

Comment: I am happy for anything that runs on *inx

Comment: Anyone trying to do this sort of simple name processing is going to annoying someone at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open(my $IN, "<infile.txt") or die $!;
chomp(my @lines = <$IN>);
close $IN;

foreach(@lines){
  s/^(GIVEN\=.+)\s+(\S+)$/$1\nLAST=$2/;
}

open(my $OUT,">outfile.txt") or die $!;
print "$_\n" foreach(@lines);
close $OUT;
```

Should work.  Modify as needed to read line by line if input file is very large.

Comment: Thanks it working good, I am running it over multiple files like this.    `find . -type f -name \*.txt |xargs perl -i -ple 's/^(GIVEN\=.+)\s+(\S+)$/$1\nLAST=$2/'`

Comment: There is no need to escape "=" because it's not in the "dirty dozen": \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ? .

Comment: Why start off reading the whole file at one and suggesting to modify it to line by line later? Just start off that way. It's no harder and doesn't cause problems later.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk ' /^GIVEN=/ {last=$NF; $NF=""; print; print "LAST=" last; next} 1' filename
```

Comment: This will not modify the original line.

Answer (score 1):

The [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/substr.html) and [rindex](http://perldoc.perl.org/rindex.html) operators are especially designed for this task. The [rindex](http://perldoc.perl.org/rindex.html) finds the position of first occurrence of a character starting on the right hand side of a string, and the [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/substr.html) takes a position and length to insert a substring:

This [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/substr.html) works on `$_`, starts at the position given by `rindex`, substitutes the next `1` character with `\nLAST=`:

```
while( <> ) {
    substr( $_, rindex( $_, ' ' ), 1, "\nLAST=" ) if /\AGIVEN=/;
    print;
    }
```

When you look at this code, you see that it is already in the form of the you need for a one-liner, although in that case, I use generalized quoting to avoid shell interpolation issues:

```
% perl -pi.old -e 'substr($_,rindex($_,q( )),1,qq(\nLAST=)) if /\AGIVEN=/' ...
```

This, however, is likely to mangle some people's names. Not every surname is a single word. Asking the person is the only good way to know what their last name is.

Answer (score 0):

```
thames.434> cat file
    FOO=Bar
    GIVEN=David Smith
    Baz=123

thames.435> awk '{if ($0~/GIVEN/){x=$2;$2="";print;print "LAST=",x}else print}' file
    FOO=Bar
GIVEN=David 
LAST= Smith
    Baz=123
```